# How to stream webcam video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am very new to ffmpeg and just read some examples on how to open a video file and decode its stream.
But is it possible to open a webcam's stream, something like:

```
http://192.168.1.173:80/live/0/mjpeg.jpg?x.mjpeg
```

Is there any examples/tutorials on this?
I need to use ffmpeg as decoder to decode the stream in my own Qt based program.

Comment: _"Is there any examples/tutorials on this?"_ Tons of, google _"ffmpeg streaming"_. In the top results you''l find e.g. [this article](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide) that includes a handling webcam source IIRC. And how does this relate to c++ BTW?

Comment: Yes, I need to use it as decoder to decode streams in my own Qt based program. I cannot find any tutorials about that...

Comment: Well, as far for your Qt program, I'd say you can just call `ffmpeg` via `system()` or such (probably Qt provides it's own classes/functions to start another process from with in your program).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ > How does this relate to C++? FFmpeg provides libraries (ISO C90 with some C99 features). As long as he wraps them in an `extern "C"` he will be able to use them if needed.

Comment: @aergistal I don't see a need to use ffmpegs C-API for streaming from a webcam? This API is even harder to use then just call `ffmpeg` as a separate process (given the plethora of options, that's hard enough already).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Depends what he's trying to accomplish. If he needs to decode it to do something like motion detection then a system call won't do. He mentioned OpenCV in another question so I assume he's after frame data.

Answer (score 3):

Nyaruko,

First check if your webcam is supported... Do

```
ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -i list
```

Next ,

```
ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -r 25 -i 0 out.mp4 for encoding
```

This site has helpful info;

http://www.area536.com/projects/streaming-video/

Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This works for live video streaming:

```
ffplay -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -i video0
```

The other option using ffmpeg is:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -i video0 -f sdl2 -
```

Above both the solution are provided by FFMPED